# Bibliography: alphabetical order taking in count shorthand

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Is there a possibility to get a bibliography entry in alphabetical order in the way that it’s sorted after the shorthand’s ‘title’ (and not the author of the work)? Thanks to @moewe for helping me out all the time, the following code being copied from one of his answers (with the Vernay entry that is added):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  innameidem=true,
  maxcitenames=2,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\adddot\space}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
  \printfield{shorthand}%
  \setunit*{\addspace=\space}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL: <\url{#1}>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hrsg\adddot},
  editors = {Hrsg\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}{%
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext{\mkbibbrackets{\printorigdate}}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}
  }%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
       \printfield[superedition]{edition}%
       \global\clearfield{edition}%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\sernumdelim}%
       \printfield{number}}}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Battaglia,
  author    = {Battaglia, Salvatore},
  title     = {Grande dizionario della lingua italiana},
  publisher = {UTET},
  date      = {1961/2008},
  address   = {Turin},
  volumes   = 21,
  shorthand = {GDLI},
}
@mvbook{Vernay,
  author    = {Vernay, Henri},
  title     = {Dictionnaire onomasiologique des langues romanes},
  publisher = {Niemeyer},
  date      = {1991},
  address   = {Tübingen},
  volume    = 1,
  shorthand = {DOLR},
}
@book{Holtus,
  editor    = {Günther, Holtus and Metzeltin, Michael and Schmitt, Christian},
  maintitle = {Lexikon der Romanistischen Linguistik},
  title     = {Kontakt, Migration und Kunstsprachen.
               Kontrastivität, Klassifikation und Typologie},
  volume    = {7},
  address   = {Tübingen},
  publisher = {Niemeyer},
  shorthand = {LRL7},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Il participio dei verbi intransitivi coniugati con *essere* è accordato con il soggetto}
\autocite[117]{Battaglia}

Lorem \autocite{Holtus,sigfridsson,Vernay}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So by default, the work DOLR must be the last entry listed because of it’s author’s last name. However, I’d like it to be shown at the very beginning, so that it is sorted after the shorthand (D being the first letter among the given entries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the sorting scheme so that it takes the `shorthand` into account by inserting a `\field{shorthand}` in the desired place.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  innameidem=true,
  maxcitenames=2,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\adddot\space}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
  \printfield{shorthand}%
  \setunit*{\addspace=\space}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL: <\url{#1}>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hrsg\adddot},
  editors = {Hrsg\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}{%
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext{\mkbibbrackets{\printorigdate}}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}
  }%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
       \printfield[superedition]{edition}%
       \global\clearfield{edition}%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\sernumdelim}%
       \printfield{number}}}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{shorthand}
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Battaglia,
  author    = {Battaglia, Salvatore},
  title     = {Grande dizionario della lingua italiana},
  publisher = {UTET},
  date      = {1961/2008},
  address   = {Turin},
  volumes   = 21,
  shorthand = {GDLI},
}
@mvbook{Vernay,
  author    = {Vernay, Henri},
  title     = {Dictionnaire onomasiologique des langues romanes},
  publisher = {Niemeyer},
  date      = {1991},
  address   = {Tübingen},
  volume    = 1,
  shorthand = {DOLR},
}
@book{Holtus,
  editor    = {Günther, Holtus and Metzeltin, Michael and Schmitt, Christian},
  maintitle = {Lexikon der Romanistischen Linguistik},
  title     = {Kontakt, Migration und Kunstsprachen.
               Kontrastivität, Klassifikation und Typologie},
  volume    = {7},
  address   = {Tübingen},
  publisher = {Niemeyer},
  shorthand = {LRL7},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Il participio dei verbi intransitivi coniugati con *essere* è accordato con il soggetto}
\autocite[117]{Battaglia}

Lorem \autocite{Holtus,sigfridsson,Vernay}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: DOLR = Vernay, Henri (1991). Dictionnaire onomasiologique des langues romanes. Bd. 1. Tübingen: Niemeyer. GDLI = Battaglia, Salvatore (1961–2008). Grande dizionario della lingua italiana. 21 Bde. Turin: UTET. LRL7 = Günther, Holtus / Metzeltin, Michael / Schmitt, Christian (Hrsg.) (o.D.). Lexikon der Romanistischen Linguistik. Bd. 7: Kontakt, Migration und Kunstsprachen. Kontrastivität, Klassifikation und Typologie. Tübingen: Niemeyer. Sigfridsson, Emma / Ryde, Ulf (1998). „Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments“, in: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19(4), S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]